# How to solve this ordinary differential equation using C++ Boost odeint library

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

Using boost c++ [odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/) library, how to solve the following ordinary differential equations of motion,

> z'' = -n²·z.

The analytical solution of the aforementioned ODE is

> z(t) = (z0'/n)·sin(n·t) + z0·cos(n·t).

---

**Solution attempt as per comment (Jan 17 at 23:01) by the OP in answer**

My program is:

```
void ode( const state_type &z , state_type &dzdt , double t ) { 
    dzdt[0] = z[1]; 
    dzdt[1] = -1 * z[0] * w * w; 
} 

void write_ode( const state_type &z , const double t ) {
    cout << t << '\t' << z[0] << '\t' << z[1] << endl; 
} 

int main { ... 

    integrate( ode , z , t , 1000 , 0.1 , write_ode ); 
}
```

But the integrate function return only the values of z0, and z0'. I need to find the values of z(t).

Comment: This question is a bit too abstract and conceptual for Stack Overflow.  SO is more for getting an answer to a specific programming problem than it is for general algorithm advice (and it's certainly not for getting people to write code for you).  Once you have an algorithm and your first attempt at writing code to solve the problem, this site can help you with specifics.

Comment: z(0) and z'(0) are initial values and need to be provided by you.

Comment: Why the question has been closed? The question is not very well worded but I don't think the question need to be closed. There are several questions in here similar to this question and yet they are not closed. Please reconsider opening it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard way of transforming an N th-order differential equation of a first order ODE of dimension N. In your case this is:

```
x = z
y = dz/dt

dx/dt = y
dy/dt = n^2 x
```

You can easily put this into any solver of odeint. But, your ODE seems to be Hamiltonian - you might also think about a symplectic solver. They conserve the phase space volume and the energy "only" oscillates about the initial energy. Odeint has implemented two symplectic solvers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it, but the integrate function return only the values of z0, and z0'. I need to find the values of z(t). My program is: void ode( const state_type &z , state_type &dzdt , double t ) { dzdt[0] = z[1]; dzdt[1] = -1 * z[0] * w * w; } void write_ode( const state_type &z , const double t ) { cout << t << '\t' << z[0] << '\t' << z[1] << endl; } int main { ... integrate( ode , z , t , 1000 , 0.1 , write_ode ); }. Do you have any idea of how I do it?

Comment: Hmm, your code looks basically fine. Don't you get the time evolution of z printed on the console? Of course, after the call of integrate z will contain the current value of z. If you need the complete evolution in an array (or vector) your need to modify your observer: vector< state_type > z_eval; integrate( ode , z , t , 1000 , 0.1 , [&z_eval]( const state_type& x , double t ) { z_eval.push_back( x ); } );

Comment: Please add code and other relevant information to the question. It really belongs there and the formatting is better. With that you may even get enough votes to "reopen" the question.

Comment: What is the initialized value of `t`?

Comment: @LutzL, the initialized value of `t` is up to the OP. Starting with zero is a reasonable option. I have a full solution for this problem but the question is being closed.

Comment: I was asking because if `t` contains a value larger than 1000 (e.g. as uninitialized garbage), there will be only one line of output, if any at all.