# Design pattern of an ODE class in C++

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, numerical-methods, ode

I've been using different ODE solvers in C++, and I'm familiar with the theory behind standard and more advanced numerical methods for ODEs. What I'd like to understand is what is the "design pattern" of an ODE class. For instance, looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842900/how-to-solve-this-ordinary-differential-equation-using-c-boost-odeint-library)

we notice that the definition of the r.h.s consists of a `void` function which takes references to `z` and `dzdt` as follows:

```
void ode( const state_type &z , state_type &dzdt , double t ) { 
    dzdt[0] = z[1]; 
    dzdt[1] = -1 * z[0] * w * w; 
}
```

and then the integration is carried in the main with

```
int main() { ... 

    integrate( ode , z , t , 1000 , 0.1 , write_ode ); 
    return 0;

}
```

Of course such library is really hard-coded, but I just want to grasp the general idea behind the "stepper", let's say for explicit Euler's method.

---

Since the r.h.s is defined like in `void ode (...)`, I imagine that in the stepper part there's a call to `void ode(...)` that allows to update `dzdt`. It could be implemented as follows (using the `std::vector` class)

```
void do_step(std::vector<double>& z, double tn, double h){
    //tn current time, h time step
    std::vector<double> dzdt(2); 
    ode(tn,y,dzdt);
    z[0] += h*dzdt[0];
    z[1] += h*dzdt[1];
}
```

i.e.:

- I allocate space for the new solution vector
- compute the new state
- Update `z[0]`,`z[1]` using Euler's scheme, or whatever.

which can be called with `do_step(y,tn,h);`

Summarizing, my question is: given the definition of the r.h.s., is this the good way to define a step of a numerical method? Any reference/book with some design techniques of such a problem is highly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

I'd like to understand if I got correctly the first paragraph of Lutz's answer:

> The first idea is that the derivatives vectors for the stages of the
> RK method are made components of the solver class. This prevents
> frequent memory allocation and de-allocation/garbage collection during
> the run of the integrator.

In order to grasp the idea I wrote a classical RK4 for the harmonic oscillator x''=-(k/m)x, and also checked the goodness of the integration. I don't want any code debugging, but I don't really know if it was Lutz's meant, because the function is defined as a private member here which is of course not a good point. I'd like to use `struct` for defining the rhs. inside the class, but I don't understand in which way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>


std::vector<double> operator+(const std::vector<double>& a, const std::vector<double>& b){
    std::vector<double> ret(a.size());
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();++i){
        ret[i] = a[i]+b[i];
    }
    return ret;
}


constexpr double k = 3.0;
constexpr double m = 2.0;
constexpr double km  = k/m;

class Rk{
    
private:
    std::vector<double> f(const double t, const std::vector<double>& y){
        std::vector<double> state(2);
        state[0] = y[1];
        state[1] = -(k/m)*y[0] + t;
        return state;
    }
    
    std::vector<double> y0;
    const double T;
    double dt;
    
public:
    Rk( std::vector<double> _y0,const double _T,double _dt) : y0{_y0}, T{_T}, dt{_dt}{}
    ~Rk()=default;
    
    
    
    std::vector<double> mvec(const std::vector<double>& v, const double c) {
        //implements m*vec
        const auto size = v.size();
        std::vector<double> res(size);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            res[i] = c*v[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    
    
    
    void step(std::vector<double>& state, const double t){
        //performs a Rk4 step from time t to t+dt
        //state: current state y_1(tn),y_2(tn),...
        const double dth = 0.5*dt;
        std::vector<double> k1 = f(t,state);
        std::vector<double> k2 = f(t+dth,state+mvec(k1,0.5*dt));
        std::vector<double> k3 = f(t+dth,state+mvec(k2,0.5*dt));
        std::vector<double> k4 = f(t+dt,state+mvec(k3,dt));
        state = state + mvec ((k1+mvec(k2,2)+mvec(k3,2) + k4),dt/6.0);
    }
    
    void integrate(){
        std::vector<double> state(2);
        state = y0;
        double t =  0.0;
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<std::ceil(T/dt);++i){
            step(state,t);
            t+=dt;
            //            double err = std::fabs(std::sqrt(1/km) * std::sin(std::sqrt(km)*(t)) - state[0]);
            double err = std::fabs((1.0/9.0) * (6*t+std::sqrt(6)*std::sin(std::sqrt(km)*t)) - state[0]);
            std::cout << err <<std::endl;
            
        }
    }
    
    
};







int main(){
    const double dt = 0.01;
    std::vector<double> y0;
    y0.push_back(0.0);
    y0.push_back(1.0);
    Rk my_ode{y0,1.0,dt};
    my_ode.integrate();
    
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first idea is that the derivatives vectors for the stages of the RK method are made components of the solver class. This prevents frequent memory allocation and de-allocation/garbage collection during the run of the integrator. It would perhaps be better to use a higher-order method to see why this is useful, Euler is too trivial, may give a false intuition.

The next idea to contemplate is the use of variable, adapted step size methods. This means that you have internal steps that are performed when needed, and evaluation for external use via interpolation, usually using the "dense output" concept. There you could hide the internal steps completely, or expose them and the interpolation function/object. Both ideas can be studied in the `scipy.integrate` solvers, the old stepper class `ode` hides the internal steps, the stepper classes `RK45, Radau,...` behind the new `solve_ivp` interface implement the second concept.

Then you come rapidly to the point where you have a structured state space. One could implement the philosophy that the data has to be assembled in a flat one-dimensional vector, which is (the old) standard. Or one could equip the state space class with the necessary vector and norm operations. You should have found that in the boost::odeint template parameters.

A next point to that is that the state space may have segments, like different objects, position vs. velocity, etc., that are on vastly different magnitude scales that should be treated separately in error estimates (incl. absolute error tolerances) for the step size controller (that is, compute optimal step sizes for every segment and then take the minimum).

As a last point here, a solver only becomes universally useful if it has an event-action mechanism. Events are (directional) zero-crossings of some functions of the state, actions can be to record the event, to terminate at the event, or less standard, a modification of the state vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. The most important part to me is the first paragraph, namely "derivatives are components of the ode solver class". I edited my question with a RKclass, and I'd like to understand how to implement the concept above.

Comment: In practice, the question is: in which way  "derivatives vectors for the stages of the RK method are made components of the solver class" is implemented? I think you're referring to the fact that the rhs of the ode is the vector with derivatives, but how do you write it in your code? As a struct inside the class?  Any minimal working example is highly appreciated @LutzLehmann