# Runge Kutta 4 Implementation

Tags: python, typeerror, ode, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I am trying to implement the Runge-Kutta Method of order 4.
I get a Type Error: 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64' in the calculations of k1,k2,k3,k4. Does anyone know a workaround?

```
def rk4(f, Y0, t0, tf, n):
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, n+1)
    Y = np.array([Y0]*(n+1))
    h = t[1]-t[0]
    for i in range(n):
        k1 = h * f(Y[i], t[i])
        k2 = h * f(Y[i]+0.5*k1, t[i]+0.5*h)
        k3 = h * f(Y[i]+0.5*k2, t[i]+0.5*h)
        k4 = h * f(Y[i]+k3, t[i]+h)
        Y[i+1]  = Y[i] + (k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)/6.0

    return Y, t
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return an numpy array from your function `f`. A list can only be "multiplied" by an integer and produces repetitions by copies of the list, not what you would expect as vector multiplication.

You can solve this directly in that function by wrapping the return values in a numpy array, or by providing a wrapper

```
def rk4(f, Y0, t0, tf, n):
    func = lambda Y,t: np.array(f(Y,t))
    ...
    for i in range(n):
        k1 = h * func(Y[i], t[i])
        ...
```

Comment: your suggestion works fine, I found an alternate solution, by just casting the return value of my function f to an array by the use of the numpy numpy.asarray() function

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "directly in that function".

Comment: Maybe as a general question for these numerical integrator implementations. I implemented two different versions one which does the full integration for all time steps i need, and one which only does one time step. And then I use this timestep later to calculate my numerical solution with a new loop. I was wondering if one or the other should be prefered or does it even matter in which order i perform the steps ?

Comment: I did a longer stream-of-thought in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866887, but essentially what you should want to achieve is a reuse of the slope-vectors k1,... in some way. There are ways for both strategies, using a stepper class is usually more flexible. Overall, this is not easy in python, you would have to research every step if the data array is overwritten or changed to a newly allocated array. There are ways to always use the same array for the return value in the ODE function, which might introduce other new aliasing problems,...